# How can I write different text file name output after curl bash?

Tags: bash, loops, url, filenames

I am trying to do multiple curl operations on url which is written in the text file. The text file looks like below

```
http://example.com

http://anotherexample.com
```

And I succeded in making basic looping in bash but it does output in single text file.. whereas I want to make different files named in distictive names or just numbers.. (eg. 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt...)
How can I control my output text file name working in bash shell?
Thank You very much in advance~!! And this is what I done so far..

```
for i in $(cat some.txt); do
    content = "($curl -L "$i")"
    echo "$content" >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: You need to learn basic shell syntax. You can't have spaces around the `=` in an assignment.

Comment: `for i in $(...)` is a broken construct, it's subject to glob expansion and word-splitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable in the output file.

```
n=1
for i in $(cat some.txt): do
    curl -L "$i" > "$n.txt"
    ((n++))
done
```